# HTML/CSS Mosaic image gallery

Tags: html, css, block, tile, mosaic

I'm trying to make a couple "blocks" in html and CSS, and I'm trying to make something like the image I included. Tried looking for a template but i can't find anything like it, can any of you help me out?
(no need for the links you see on the image)

I'm only somewhat of a beginner in all this, so forgive any misunderstandings

I myself was trying this, but i can't get this to work either, probably because i'm using images instead of something else..

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<center>
        <!-- FIRST ROW -->
        <div class="row">
            <img src="http://www.cardcarryinglesbian.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/AD-SPACE2001.jpg" width="200" height="200" border="0">
            <img src="" width="200" height="200" border="0" class="img-circle">
            <img src="http://www.cardcarryinglesbian.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/AD-SPACE2001.jpg" width="200" height="200" border="0">
            <img src="" width="200" height="200" border="0" class="img-circle">
            </div>
            <p></p>
        <!-- SECOND ROW -->
          <div class="row">
            <img src="" width="200" height="200" border="0" class="img-circle">
            <img src="http://www.cardcarryinglesbian.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/AD-SPACE2001.jpg" width="200" height="200" border="0">
            <img src="" width="200" height="200" border="0" class="img-circle">
            <img src="http://www.cardcarryinglesbian.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/AD-SPACE2001.jpg" width="200" height="200" border="0">
            <p></p>
          </div>
</center>
```

Example of what I have in mind

[image]

Comment: did you try something yet ?

Comment: Nope, still kinda stuck here

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/ewRImU2EUh look at the given example maybe help you out

Answer (score 0):

Just to help you to start width. You can created a grid/table like structure in number of ways, some of them are UL LI(simplest), flex box & etc,.

here is UL LI structure

```
<div id="container">
  <ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
   <li>5</li>
   <li>6</li>
   <li>7</li>
   <li>8</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

SCSS style at JS fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/itsselvam/sgmtu6cr/

I hope this helps you to start!